# Eclipse Sharing workspace with gitlab

Tags: java, eclipse, git, gitlab

I have done some JavaEE programming projects on my Win7 computer with Eclipse, and they are in the same workspace.

Now I want to share them by putting them on gitlab.

I've created a project on gitlab, say MyProjects.

Then in Eclipse I've performed a "Clone a Git Repository and add the clone to this view.

Now how can I add to it my workspace, that's located in a different path than the git repo I've added?

Thanks and ciao

Thanks

Comment: In the Git perspective, perform a right click on the project, select `Import Projects…` and then simply use the wizard.

Comment: Instead, if you have a project in your workspace and you want to share it on GitLab, simply select the project in the Java EE perspective, perform a right click, select `Team` and then `Share Project`. After that, use the wizard to share it on a repository.

Comment: And just to be clear, **don't** share a *workspace*, share the *projects* themselves.

Comment: Why? Inside a workspace I have project that are related. My final task is to have the projects I work on on git so when I'll get out of office I can push them from a Win7 machine and pull them into an OSx machine while at home.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do it following this nice guide: [create and init multi-project repositories with EGit (Git)](https://ekkescorner.wordpress.com/blog-series/git-mercurial/workflow-create-multi-project-repositories-egit/)

I've answered my question becuase I hope this will be useful to someboby else.